# Sending file to WCF from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, wcf

I have an issue with trying to send a file from AngularJS to a WCF web service, I get alot of other calls to work, but this one wont. What I get in `UploadTest` is an empty string, if I instead of converting it to a blob just sends it in as it is and tries to recieve a `byte[]` or `List<Byte>` I get those empty. What do I do wrong?

[EDIT] 
The "stream" object does have a size on the JS side...

[EDIT2]
If I convert to String instead of Blob I can send short string, but not large ones (over 10000 in size)

Javascript

```
function selectFile() {
        var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
        var r = new FileReader();
        vm.fileName=f.name
        r.onload = function (e) {


            var dataab = r.result;
            var data = new Uint8Array(dataab);
            var saveObject = { User: $rootScope.globals.currentUser.id, Name: vm.fileName, Data: data, Fileformat: "CSV", Separator: ";" };
            FlowService.UploadTest(data)
            .then(function (result) {
                vm.uploaded = result.Success;
                if (result.Success) {
                    vm.allFiles.push({ Name: result.FileName, Id: result.Id });
                }
            });
        }

        // Read file as binary string
        //r.readAsBinaryString(f);
        // Read as arrya buffer shall be used when sending binary data. Problem is that we got zero length on wcf with both array and list

        r.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
    }


function UploadTest(str) {

        var url = "../../Service1.svc/UploadTest";
        var stream = new Blob(str);
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: { stream: stream }
        }).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error uploading file'));
    }
```

WCF

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
UploadResult UploadTest(String stream);


public UploadResult UploadTest(String stream)
{
 return new UploadResult { Message = stream, FileName = "Test", Id = -1, Success = true };
}
```

Comment: Have you tried sending a HttpPostedFile? That might be easier to work with.